# Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph, with $|V(G)|$ even, that remains connected when any $k − 2$ edges are deleted. Prove that $G$ has a $1$-factor.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph, with $|V(G)|$ even, that remains 
connected when any $k − 2$ edges are deleted. Prove that $G$ has a $1$-factor.

I'm not looking for someone to give me a formal proof, I'm just looking for ideas as to how I could go about proving this, I can then fill in the details myself.

Comment: Tutte's theorem might be useful

Answer (score 1):

In general, [Tutte's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem) is the way to guarantee a perfect matching (or $1$-factor) in an arbitrary graph. Given any set of vertices $U$, you want to show that $G - U$ has at most $|U|$ odd components.

The key is that whenever $C$ is a set of vertices that form an odd component of $G-U$, you have a cut that you can apply your hypothesis to: the edges between $C$ and $U$. There cannot be too few such edges (because $G$ is $(k-1)$-edge-connected). However, there also cannot be many odd components, each with many edges incident to $U$: there are only so many edges out of $U$ to go around.

Play these off against each other - making sure to use the parity of $|C|$ at some point - and you'll satisfy the hypotheses of Tutte's theorem.

(Once you do, I encourage you to post your solution as an answer to your own question.)

Comment: In an attempt to acquire a contradiciton I assume that $\exists U\subseteq V(G):o(G-U)>|U|$. Let $C_1,...,C_n$ be the sets of vertices that make up the odd components of $G-U$. In $G$ each $C_1$ is connected to $U$ via at least $k-1$ edges. Thus $\bigcup_{i=1}^nC_i$ is connected to $U$ via $(k-1)o(G-U)\geq (k-1)|U|+1$ edges. If I can show that there are at least $|U|$ edges contained in $U$ then $U$ has at least $(k-1)|U|+1+|U| = k|U|+1$ edges which would be a contradiciton. However I am unable to show that that there are at least $|U|$ edges contained in $U$ so I can't get a contradiciton.

Comment: There might not be $|U|$ edges contained in $U$. Rather, you should try to show that actually there cannot be $k-1$ edges out of $C_i$: there must be $k$.

Comment: Ok, I will give this another try.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I managed to solve the problem. I will post the proof later.